# Linear constraint on $\{0,1\}^n$ such that the feasible set are those vectors with a contiguous strings of ones of length $k$

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, binary-programming

I'm trying to formulate a linear constraint

$$Ax\leq b$$
$$x\in\{0,1\}^n$$

such that the feasible set is exactly those binary vectors $x$ with a single contiguous string of ones of length $k$.

For example, if $n=4$ and $k=2$, then it would be the vectors:

$$(1,1,0,0)$$
$$(0,1,1,0)$$
$$(0,0,1,1)$$

I've so far been unsuccessful at finding a suitable $A$ and $b$, can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Can you introduce two more binary vectors that indicate the start and end locations of your contiguous string? Or is that something you must avoid?

Comment: @LinAlg Sure I don't see why not if you think that will help.

Comment: I'd say the problem becomes trivial that way. Let me know if you still need a full solution.

Comment: @LinAlg could you explain a bit more about how you introduce these new binary variables into the constraint, is the constraint still of the form $Ax\leq b$?

Comment: The new constraint not only constrains $x$, but also the new vectors. That is why I was asking if that's a problem.

Comment: @LinAlg like something of the form $Ax + Gz \leq b$?  Or multiple separate linear constraints?

Comment: Yes something of that form. Is it trivial now or are you still interested in a solution like that?

Comment: @LinAlg, I'm afraid I still can't see how this helps, could you provide a solution?

Comment: Please accept the answer or indicate why it is not satisfactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding two binary vectors that indicate the start and end locations of your contiguous string, $b_1$ and $b_2$, the problem can be formulated as:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} x_j \leq (i-1) - (i-1)(b_1)_i \quad \forall i\\
\sum_{j=i+1}^{n} x_j \leq (n-i) - (n-i)(b_2)_i \quad \forall i \\
x_i \geq \sum_{j=1}^i (b_1)_j - \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} (b_2)_j \quad \forall i\\
\sum_{i=1}^n (b_1)_i = 1 \\
\sum_{i=1}^n (b_2)_i = 1 \\
x, b_1, b_2 \in \{0,1\}^n
\end{align*}
$$
Let $l$ and $r$ denote the index where $b_1=1$ resp. $b_2=1$.
The first two constraints ensure that $x_j=0$ for $j<l$ and for $j>r$. The third constraint sets $x_i=1$ if $l \leq i \leq r$.

You can transform equality constraints into inequalities. You can then rewrite the constraints as $Ax + Gb_1 + Hb_2 \leq b$.

**Alternative solution** If you do not want to add additional variables, you have to add many logical statements of the form $x_3=0 \wedge x_5=1 \Rightarrow x_1=0$. This particular one can be formulated as $x_1 \leq 1+x_3-x_5$.